# How to send both Image and JSON through ajax apache CXF

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, cxf

I am trying to develop a screen to send both json and image as part of the same request.

I am able to send both json and image in two different calls but I need to send both in the same.

Below is my screen which contains my java script code. I am using apache CXF as my rest component.

```js
   var table = $('#familyDetails').tableToJSON();
  var kovilRequestDTO={
  "familyDetailsList" : table,
  };
  var data=JSON.stringify(kovilRequestDTO);
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('kovilRequestDTO', data);
  formData.append('familHeadImage', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8091/KovilRestServices/kovilRestService/uploadFile", 
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
       processData: false,
         dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
      $( "#message-box h2" ).html("Your registration is successful."+response.familyHeadId);
      $(".message-box").fadeIn("fast");
      } 
   });
```

```html
<body>
 <input id="add_new" type="button" value="Add Record" />
 <input type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="my-button" value="Add image">
<!-- <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my-file"> -->

 <form style="display:none" name="fileUploadForm" id="fileUploadForm"
  action="http://localhost:8091/KovilRestServices/kovilRestService/uploadFile"
  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
   Select a file : <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my_file" size="50" />
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" name="familyHeadId"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
 </form>

</body>
</html>
<div class="addmembertable">
 <table id="familyDetails" class="table-list" border="0" width="70%"
  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Relation</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Qualification</th>
    <th>PID</th>
    <th>Profession</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div id="message-box" class="message-box" style="display: none;">
 <h2></h2>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="OK" id="OK"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="entry-form">
 <form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="name" name="name"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Relation</td>
    <td><select id="relation" class="relation">
      <option selected>--select--</option>
      <option value="Family Head">Family Head</option>
      <option value="Son">Son</option>
      <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
      <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
      <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
      <option value="Father">Father</option>
    </select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>DOB</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="dob" name="dob"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Relation</td>
    <td><select id="gender" class="gender" name="gender">
      <option selected>--select--</option>
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
    </select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Qualification</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qualification"
     name="qualification"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Parental ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="parentalID" name="parentalID"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Profession</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="profession" name="profession"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="phone" name="phone"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="email" name="email"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="address" name="address"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="save"><input
     type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</div>
<div class="addmemberfooter">
 <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
</body>
```

[image: Screen with table data and image]

My Rest Implementation is below. I get a 404 error when I invoke it. Other rest endpoints are which are working are configured in the same way. I have used apache CXF for rest implementation

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("application/json")
public Response testDownload(
        @FormParam(value="kovilRequestDTO") KovilRequestDTO kovilRequestDTO,
        @FormParam(value="familHeadImage") Attachment attachment);
```

Error Stack Trace :

```
WARNING: No operation matching request path "/KovilRestServices/kovilRestService/uploadFile" is found, Relative Path: /uploadFile, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAmzgeu8Y86sBX7m2, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
```

Comment: not hard to research how to do file uploads with ajax

Comment: @charlietfl I need to send both image and pojo in the same request. In my case I have a table which I am converting to JSON being mapped to Pojo.Along with this I need to send the image file as well

Comment: not hard using FormData API and appropriate ajax settings

Comment: @charlietfl could you please check my setting and let me know where i am going wrong.I am unable to figure it out. I am trying to send both table which is being converted to json and the image.The json will be binded to a pojo in the backend. When i try to invoke the call it gives me 404 error